# Message update in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to AngularJS and having an issue with updating message for either the for loop or angular.

Right now the two Angular functions (login and register) are only working for the last User, "Bilbo".

1. The login function does not return the appropriate message for if the User exists but the password is not correct, for all users except the last user, Bilbo.
2. For the register function it should be constantly checking to see if a name is taken or free, but it only says taken for the last user as well, Bilbo.

Not sure what I am doing wrong with combination of the for-loop and AngularJS as I would like to the message to work on all users.

**[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/uhwXJ456OyRFQbXnz1rS?p=preview)**

**JS Code**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  })

  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  })

  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
  })

  .when('/account', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/account.html',
    controller: 'AccountController'
  })

  .when('/unknown', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/unknown.html',
    controller: 'UnknownController'
  })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/unknown'
    });
});


app.factory('userService', function() {
  return {
    users: [{
      name: "John",
      password: "12345"
    }, {
      name: "Austin",
      password: "intern"
    }, {
      name: "Sally",
      password: "noob"
    }, {
      name: "Bilbo",
      password: "Baggins"
    }]

  };
});

app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $location, userService) {
  $scope.credentials = {
    username: "",
    password: ""
  };
  $scope.credentialsR = {
    username: "",
    password: ""
  };

  $scope.login = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < userService.users.length; i++) {
      if (userService.users[i].name === $scope.credentials.username) {
        if (userService.users[i].password === $scope.credentials.password) {
          $location.path("/home");
        } else {
          $scope.messageLogin = "Incorrect login details";
        }
      } else {
        $scope.messageLogin = "Username does not exist";
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.checkName = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < userService.users.length; i++) {
      if (userService.users[i].name === $scope.credentialsR.username) {
        $scope.messageRegister = "Taken";
      } else {
        $scope.messageRegister = "Available";
      }
    }
  };
});

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {

});

app.controller('AccountController', function($scope, userService) {
  $scope.userList = userService.users;
});

app.controller('UnknownController', function($scope) {

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to immediately return if the user is found in the loop, instead of continue looping.

```
$scope.login = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < userService.users.length; i++) {
    if (userService.users[i].name === $scope.credentials.username) {
      if (userService.users[i].password === $scope.credentials.password) {
        $location.path("/home");
      } else {
        $scope.messageLogin = "Incorrect login details";
      }

      return;
    }
  }

  $scope.messageLogin = "Username does not exist";
};

$scope.checkName = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < userService.users.length; i++) {
    if (userService.users[i].name === $scope.credentialsR.username) {
      $scope.messageRegister = "Taken";
      return;
    }
  }

  $scope.messageRegister = "Available";
};
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/eBGLsBdI89WFhEAxyDgL?p=preview

Comment: ahhh derp. haha thank you! Quick side question, is there any way to add styles in JS that will update on the fly? i.e. Make Available green and Taken red.

Comment: You could use `ng-class` for that, check the plunker again I've updated it.

Comment: I suggest you put both messages in separate elements in the HTML, each with their own style, and activate / deactivate them with ngIf directives mapped to boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you do not exit the for loop after having found the matching name. Therefore, if the matching name is not the last, the following name will trigger the wrong behavior anyway.

You can use a `return` to exit the loop, or more elegantly separate the search with a dedicated function:

```
app.factory('userService', function() {
  var users = [{
    name: "John",
    password: "12345"
  }, {
    name: "Austin",
    password: "intern"
  }, {
    name: "Sally",
    password: "noob"
  }, {
    name: "Bilbo",
    password: "Baggins"
  }];
  return {
    users: users,
    findUserByName: function (userName) {
      return users.filter(function (user) {
        return user.name === userName;
      })[0];
    }
  };
});
```

And then :

```
$scope.login = function() {
  var user = userService.findUserByName($scope.credentials.username);
  if(user) {
    if(user.password ===  $scope.credentials.password){
      $location.path("/home");
    } else {
      $scope.messageLogin = "Incorrect login details";
    }
  } else {
    $scope.messageLogin = "Username does not exist";
  }
};

$scope.checkName = function() {
  var user = userService.findUserByName($scope.credentials.username);
  if(user) {
    $scope.messageRegister = "Taken";
  } else {
    $scope.messageRegister = "Available";
  }
};
```